# Special two-state button in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, button, interaction

In InDesign, I want to make button with two states, just like on the example:

[image]

The normal state is a circle, so if I move the mouse over it, an info box pops up. That is a nice feature in an interactive PDF presentation where you want to inform somebody about something.

Now here is the problem:

[image]

If I move my cursor next to the circle, the button changes it's state to Rollover.
(The white box shows the bounding area of the objects.)

[image]

Is it possible to restrict the Rollover area to the circle, so the info box shows up only when you move the mouse over the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping both objects into the same button (even if the grouped version is only visible during the Rollover State) turns the total area of both objects and the space between them into the Rollover Area. To avoid this, **create *two* *separate* buttons, and have one button "control" the other**:

1. Turn the rectangle pop-up into its own button called **Rectangle**, and turn the circle into its own button called **Circle**.
2. Select the **Rectangle** button.
3. Under **Appearance**, check the **Hidden Until Triggered** box.
   [image: Hide Rectangle button until triggered.]
4. Select the **Circle** button.
5. Under **Event**, select **On Roll Over**.
6. Click the **Plus Sign** next to **Actions**, and select **Show/Hide Buttons and Forms**.
7. Under **Visibility**, click the **(X)** next to the **Rectangle** button until it changes to an **Eye**.
   [image: Circle Roll Over options.]
8. Under **Event**, select **On Roll Off**.
9. Click the **Plus Sign** next to **Actions**, and select **Show/Hide Buttons and Forms**.
10. Under **Visibility**, click the **(X)** next to the **Rectangle** button until it changes to an **Eye With Red Line** through it.
    [image: Circle Roll Off options.]

Render the interactive PDF, and you should see only the circle. Roll over the circle, and the rectangle should appear. Roll off, and the rectangle should disappear. No other area should trigger the rectangle pop-up. You can set up this relationship with multiple buttons in your document—just make sure you name each button carefully so that you can keep track of them!